# Expression of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, macros, expression

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CVAL(p) (*(p++))

int main()
{

    int code[4] = {2, 100, 200};

    int nn=0;

    printf("code[0] address = %p\n", &code[0]);
    printf("nn      address = %p\n", &nn);
    printf("nn      content= %i\n\n", nn);

    int *pt = &code[0];

    nn = CVAL(pt); /*<-- line 18!*/

    printf("nn    address = %p\n", &nn);
    printf("nn    content = %i\n\n", nn);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and your output is:

```
code[0] address = 0028FF2C
nn      address = 0028FF28
nn      content= 0

nn2    address = 0028FF28
nn2    content = 2
```

But when I change the expression and separate it (line 18 and line 19), the result of nn2 changes! before 2, now it's 100. Why?

```
...
    pt++;/*<-- line 18!*/
    nn = *pt;/*<-- line 19*/
...
```

Output:

```
code[0] address = 0028FF2C
nn      address = 0028FF28
nn      content= 0

nn2    address = 0028FF28
nn2    content = 100
```

Comment: `int *pt = &code[0];` is the same as `int *pt = code;`. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In First scenario your code looks like below

```
int code[4] = {2, 100, 200};
int nn=0;
int *pt = &code[0];
nn = (*(pt++)); /* post increments on pointer i.e first assign then increment */
```

after macro replacement is done by preprocessor. So here

```
nn = (*(pt++));
```

first `pt++` solved which is post increments i.e `pt` points to base address of array `code` still and dereferencing will assign `2` to `nn` so it prints `2`.

In second scenario when

```
pt++;/* here pt points to same address but in next statement it will points to incremented address */ 
nn = *pt; /* here pt pointing to code[1] address */
```

Here when `nn = *pt` executed, `pt` points to `code[1]` address hence `nn` gets assigned with `100`.

you can easily understand whats happening above by analyzing below two scenarios.

**Case 1 :-**

```
int var1 = 10, var2;
var2 = var1++; /* in this statement var2 gets assigned with 10, not incremented one as this is post increment */
printf("%d\n",var2);
```

**Case 2 :-**

```
int var1 = 10, var2;
var1++;
var2 = var1; /* now here incremented var1 gets assigned to var2 */
printf("%d\n",var2);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
nn = CVAL(pt); /*<-- line 18!*/
```

with the macro expanded that's

```
nn = *pt++;
```

And since the postfix increment does the increment *after* using the old value, it's equivalent to

```
nn = *pt;
pt += 1;
```

This is quite different from your second version, which does the dereference and increment in the opposite order.